# start-process permissions in Windows

Tags: process, shell-command, subprocess

I can open an HTML file using shell command: `M-! start file.html`, but when I try to write an elisp function which includes the line (some of these arguments are actually variables but I've written out what it would actually be in this example):

```
(start-process "view-html" "*Messages*" "start" "file.html")
```

and call it from some keybindings, I get the following error message:

```
apply: Searching for program: Permission denied, start
```

How can I call `"start"` from within an elisp function?

Comment: That sounds like more of a Windows question than an Emacs question. You should research windows permissions to see why it won’t let you run it.

Comment: I debated where to post this but since it works from `shell-command` it seems like a difference between `shell-command` and `start-process`, which is emacs-specific.

Comment: I'm able to open the HTML file if I replace "start" with "explorer.exe" (or just "explorer") so it must be something with `start-process` of emacs and "start" of Windows.